# Scrapy: Max file size errors

Tags: python, scrapy

I am having a problem trying to download a large ~ 1.8gb file using Scrapy, my code:

```
import scrapy

class CHSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "ch_accountdata"
    allowed_domains = ['download.companieshouse.gov.uk']
    start_urls = ['http://download.companieshouse.gov.uk/en_monthlyaccountsdata.html']

    custom_settings = {
        'DOWNLOAD_WARNSIZE': 0,
    }

    def parse(self, response):
        relative_url = response.xpath("//div[@class='grid_7 push_1 omega']/ul/li[12]/a/@href").extract()[0]
        download_url = response.urljoin(relative_url)
        yield {
            'file_urls': [download_url]
        }
```

This returns an error:

```html
2017-08-01 17:10:33 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 1.4.0 started (bot: develop)
2017-08-01 17:10:33 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Overridden settings: {'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'develop.spiders', 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['develop.spiders'], 'ROBOTSTXT_OBEY': True, 'BOT_NAME': 'develop'}
2017-08-01 17:10:33 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats']
2017-08-01 17:10:34 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.robotstxt.RobotsTxtMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2017-08-01 17:10:34 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2017-08-01 17:10:34 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
['scrapy.pipelines.files.FilesPipeline']
2017-08-01 17:10:34 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2017-08-01 17:10:34 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2017-08-01 17:10:34 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6024
2017-08-01 17:10:35 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (404) <GET http://download.companieshouse.gov.uk/robots.txt> (referer: None)
2017-08-01 17:10:35 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://download.companieshouse.gov.uk/en_monthlyaccountsdata.html> (referer: None)
2017-08-01 17:10:35 [scrapy.core.downloader.handlers.http11] ERROR: Cancelling download of http://download.companieshouse.gov.uk/Accounts_Monthly_Data-June2017.zip: expected response size (1240658506) larger than download max size (1073741824).
2017-08-01 17:10:35 [scrapy.pipelines.files] WARNING: File (unknown-error): Error downloading file from <GET http://download.companieshouse.gov.uk/Accounts_Monthly_Data-June2017.zip> referred in <None>: Cancelling download of http://download.companieshouse.gov.uk/Accounts_Monthly_Data-June2017.zip: expected response size (1240658506) larger than download max size (1073741824).
2017-08-01 17:10:35 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://download.companieshouse.gov.uk/en_monthlyaccountsdata.html>
{'files': [], 'file_urls': [u'http://download.companieshouse.gov.uk/Accounts_Monthly_Data-June2017.zip']}
2017-08-01 17:10:35 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2017-08-01 17:10:35 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/exception_count': 1,
 'downloader/exception_type_count/twisted.internet.defer.CancelledError': 1,
 'downloader/request_bytes': 755,
 'downloader/request_count': 3,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 3,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 11061,
 'downloader/response_count': 2,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 1,
 'downloader/response_status_count/404': 1,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2017, 8, 1, 16, 10, 35, 806000),
 'item_scraped_count': 1,
 'log_count/DEBUG': 4,
 'log_count/ERROR': 1,
 'log_count/INFO': 7,
 'log_count/WARNING': 1,
 'response_received_count': 2,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 1,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2017, 8, 1, 16, 10, 34, 559000)}
2017-08-01 17:10:35 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

I have since added the following to the custom settings:

```
'DOWNLOAD_MAXSIZE' : 0,
'DOWNLOAD_TIMEOUT': 600
```

This makes a different error, Scrapy doesn't seem to stop:

```html
2017-08-01 16:41:47 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 1.4.0 started (bot: develop)
2017-08-01 16:41:47 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Overridden settings: {'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'develop.spiders', 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['develop.spiders'], 'ROBOTSTXT_OBEY': True, 'BOT_NAME': 'develop'}
2017-08-01 16:41:47 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats']
2017-08-01 16:41:48 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.robotstxt.RobotsTxtMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2017-08-01 16:41:48 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2017-08-01 16:41:48 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
['scrapy.pipelines.files.FilesPipeline']
2017-08-01 16:41:48 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2017-08-01 16:41:48 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2017-08-01 16:41:48 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6024
2017-08-01 16:41:50 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (404) <GET http://download.companieshouse.gov.uk/robots.txt> (referer: None)
2017-08-01 16:41:50 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://download.companieshouse.gov.uk/en_monthlyaccountsdata.html> (referer: None)
2017-08-01 16:42:48 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 2 pages (at 2 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2017-08-01 16:43:48 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 2 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2017-08-01 16:44:48 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 2 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
Unhandled Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\endpoints.py", line 125, in dataReceived
    return self._wrappedProtocol.dataReceived(data)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\web\_newclient.py", line 1595, in dataReceived
    self._giveUp(Failure())
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\web\_newclient.py", line 1585, in _giveUp
    self._disconnectParser(reason)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\web\_newclient.py", line 1573, in _disconnectParser
    parser.connectionLost(reason)
--- <exception caught here> ---
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\web\_newclient.py", line 558, in connectionLost
    self.response)))
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\web\_newclient.py", line 964, in dispatcher
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\web\_newclient.py", line 1220, in _bodyDataFinished_CONNECTED
    self._bodyProtocol.connectionLost(reason)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\downloader\handlers\http11.py", line 434, in connectionLost
    body = self._bodybuf.getvalue()
exceptions.MemoryError:

2017-08-01 16:45:29 [twisted] CRITICAL: Unhandled Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\endpoints.py", line 125, in dataReceived
    return self._wrappedProtocol.dataReceived(data)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\web\_newclient.py", line 1595, in dataReceived
    self._giveUp(Failure())
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\web\_newclient.py", line 1585, in _giveUp
    self._disconnectParser(reason)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\web\_newclient.py", line 1573, in _disconnectParser
    parser.connectionLost(reason)
--- <exception caught here> ---
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\web\_newclient.py", line 558, in connectionLost
    self.response)))
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\web\_newclient.py", line 964, in dispatcher
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\web\_newclient.py", line 1220, in _bodyDataFinished_CONNECTED
    self._bodyProtocol.connectionLost(reason)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\downloader\handlers\http11.py", line 434, in connectionLost
    body = self._bodybuf.getvalue()
exceptions.MemoryError:

2017-08-01 16:45:48 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 2 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2017-08-01 16:46:48 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 2 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2017-08-01 16:47:48 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 2 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2017-08-01 16:48:48 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 2 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2017-08-01 16:49:48 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 2 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2017-08-01 16:50:48 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 2 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2017-08-01 16:51:48 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 2 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
Unhandled Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\commands\crawl.py", line 58, in run
    self.crawler_process.start()
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 285, in start
    reactor.run(installSignalHandlers=False)  # blocking call
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\base.py", line 1243, in run
    self.mainLoop()
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\base.py", line 1252, in mainLoop
    self.runUntilCurrent()
--- <exception caught here> ---
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\base.py", line 878, in runUntilCurrent
    call.func(*call.args, **call.kw)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 547, in cancel
    self.result.cancel()
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 536, in cancel
    canceller(self)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\downloader\handlers\http11.py", line 352, in _cancel
    txresponse._transport._producer.abortConnection()
exceptions.AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'abortConnection'

2017-08-01 16:51:50 [twisted] CRITICAL: Unhandled Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\commands\crawl.py", line 58, in run
    self.crawler_process.start()
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 285, in start
    reactor.run(installSignalHandlers=False)  # blocking call
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\base.py", line 1243, in run
    self.mainLoop()
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\base.py", line 1252, in mainLoop
    self.runUntilCurrent()
--- <exception caught here> ---
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\base.py", line 878, in runUntilCurrent
    call.func(*call.args, **call.kw)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 547, in cancel
    self.result.cancel()
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 536, in cancel
    canceller(self)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\downloader\handlers\http11.py", line 352, in _cancel
    txresponse._transport._producer.abortConnection()
exceptions.AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'abortConnection'

2017-08-01 16:52:48 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 2 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2017-08-01 16:53:48 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 2 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2017-08-01 16:54:48 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 2 pages (at 0 pages/min),
```

Edit - full settings.py file:

```html
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Scrapy settings for develop project
#
# For simplicity, this file contains only settings considered important or
# commonly used. You can find more settings consulting the documentation:
#
#     http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html
#     http://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html
#     http://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/spider-middleware.html

BOT_NAME = 'develop'

SPIDER_MODULES = ['develop.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'develop.spiders'


# Crawl responsibly by identifying yourself (and your website) on the user-agent
#USER_AGENT = 'develop (+http://www.yourdomain.com)'

# Obey robots.txt rules
ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = True

# Configure maximum concurrent requests performed by Scrapy (default: 16)
#CONCURRENT_REQUESTS = 32

# Configure a delay for requests for the same website (default: 0)
# See http://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#download-delay
# See also autothrottle settings and docs
#DOWNLOAD_DELAY = 3
# The download delay setting will honor only one of:
#CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN = 16
#CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_IP = 16

# Disable cookies (enabled by default)
#COOKIES_ENABLED = False

# Disable Telnet Console (enabled by default)
#TELNETCONSOLE_ENABLED = False

# Override the default request headers:
#DEFAULT_REQUEST_HEADERS = {
#   'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
#   'Accept-Language': 'en',
#}

# Enable or disable spider middlewares
# See http://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/spider-middleware.html
#SPIDER_MIDDLEWARES = {
#    'develop.middlewares.DevelopSpiderMiddleware': 543,
#}

# Enable or disable downloader middlewares
# See http://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html
#DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
#    'develop.middlewares.MyCustomDownloaderMiddleware': 543,
#}

# Enable or disable extensions
# See http://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/extensions.html
#EXTENSIONS = {
#    'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole': None,
#}

# Configure item pipelines
# See http://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html
#ITEM_PIPELINES = {
#    'develop.pipelines.DevelopPipeline': 300,
ITEM_PIPELINES = {'scrapy.pipelines.files.FilesPipeline': 1}
FILES_STORE = '/Users/MichaelAnderson/GDrive/Python/develop/data'
#}

# Enable and configure the AutoThrottle extension (disabled by default)
# See http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/autothrottle.html
#AUTOTHROTTLE_ENABLED = True
# The initial download delay
#AUTOTHROTTLE_START_DELAY = 5
# The maximum download delay to be set in case of high latencies
#AUTOTHROTTLE_MAX_DELAY = 60
# The average number of requests Scrapy should be sending in parallel to
# each remote server
#AUTOTHROTTLE_TARGET_CONCURRENCY = 1.0
# Enable showing throttling stats for every response received:
#AUTOTHROTTLE_DEBUG = False

# Enable and configure HTTP caching (disabled by default)
# See http://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html#httpcache-middleware-settings
#HTTPCACHE_ENABLED = True
#HTTPCACHE_EXPIRATION_SECS = 0
#HTTPCACHE_DIR = 'httpcache'
#HTTPCACHE_IGNORE_HTTP_CODES = []
#HTTPCACHE_STORAGE = 'scrapy.extensions.httpcache.FilesystemCacheStorage'
```

I have not added anything to pipelines.py.

Items.py looks like:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.item import Item, Field

class FiledownloadItem(Item):
    file_urls = Field()
    files = Field()
```

I have changed the order of the custom settings:

```
custom_settings = {
'DOWNLOAD_TIMEOUT': 60000,
'DOWNLOAD_MAXSIZE': 12406585060,
'DOWNLOAD_WARNSIZE': 0
}
```

And have a connection lost error:

```html
2017-08-04 16:29:05 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 1.4.0 started (bot: develop)
2017-08-04 16:29:05 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Overridden settings: {'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'develop.spiders', 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['develop.spiders'], 'ROBOTSTXT_OBEY': True, 'BOT_NAME': 'develop'}
2017-08-04 16:29:05 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats']
2017-08-04 16:29:05 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.robotstxt.RobotsTxtMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2017-08-04 16:29:05 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2017-08-04 16:29:05 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
['scrapy.pipelines.files.FilesPipeline']
2017-08-04 16:29:05 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2017-08-04 16:29:05 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2017-08-04 16:29:06 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2017-08-04 16:29:07 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (404) <GET http://download.companieshouse.gov.uk/robots.txt> (referer: None)
2017-08-04 16:29:07 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://download.companieshouse.gov.uk/en_monthlyaccountsdata.html> (referer: None)
2017-08-04 16:30:05 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 2 pages (at 2 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2017-08-04 16:31:05 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 2 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
Unhandled Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\endpoints.py", line 125, in dataReceived
    return self._wrappedProtocol.dataReceived(data)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\web\_newclient.py", line 1595, in dataReceived
    self._giveUp(Failure())
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\web\_newclient.py", line 1585, in _giveUp
    self._disconnectParser(reason)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\web\_newclient.py", line 1573, in _disconnectParser
    parser.connectionLost(reason)
--- <exception caught here> ---
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\web\_newclient.py", line 558, in connectionLost
    self.response)))
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\web\_newclient.py", line 964, in dispatcher
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\web\_newclient.py", line 1220, in _bodyDataFinished_CONNECTED
    self._bodyProtocol.connectionLost(reason)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\downloader\handlers\http11.py", line 434, in connectionLost
    body = self._bodybuf.getvalue()
exceptions.MemoryError:

2017-08-04 16:31:27 [twisted] CRITICAL: Unhandled Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\endpoints.py", line 125, in dataReceived
    return self._wrappedProtocol.dataReceived(data)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\web\_newclient.py", line 1595, in dataReceived
    self._giveUp(Failure())
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\web\_newclient.py", line 1585, in _giveUp
    self._disconnectParser(reason)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\web\_newclient.py", line 1573, in _disconnectParser
    parser.connectionLost(reason)
--- <exception caught here> ---
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\web\_newclient.py", line 558, in connectionLost
    self.response)))
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\web\_newclient.py", line 964, in dispatcher
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\web\_newclient.py", line 1220, in _bodyDataFinished_CONNECTED
    self._bodyProtocol.connectionLost(reason)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\downloader\handlers\http11.py", line 434, in connectionLost
    body = self._bodybuf.getvalue()
exceptions.MemoryError:

2017-08-04 16:32:05 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 2 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2017-08-04 16:33:05 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 2 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
```

Am I trying to get Scrapy to do something it can't handle?
Many thanks for any help

Answer (score 1):

I am noticing a discrepancy between the error log rather the first error log comparing it to the spider script you have provided.

Given the fact that I might not get the entire picture since you only provided the spider,  you should also have provided the pipeline and entire settings  file.  I'll go ahead and work off the stack trace, that should suffice for the moment in order to give you an adequate answer.

As to the discrepancy...

```
yield {
    'file_urls': [download_url]
}

#First Error Log Line 36

{'files': [], 'file_urls': [u'http://download.companieshouse.gov.uk/Accounts_Monthly_Data-June2017.zip']}
```

Assuming that you might not have gone over scrapy's official Docs on downloading in depth.   When it comes to downloading anything with scrapy there are a couple of musts:

1. In your items.py file,  whether you are downloading images or files ( I really don't see the difference  the naming one or the other...  To me it's all files but hey,  read the docs lol)  you must provide the following sentences or keys for your items. 'files' or 'images'... and 'file_url' or 'image_url'.   I'll give you a hint: when you end up declaring in your spider the the response path to your url to whatever you're trying to download,  the files or images response path 2 should be the same exact one.
2. In your settings.py  File,  enabling the items pipeline, Weatherby images pipeline or files pipeline is another necessary step,  also including a directory path to where the files will be stored is important as well as far the other settings that you speak of such as the max download and download time out or whatever or not exactly necessary art requirement to get the files downloaded,
3. And lastly,  one of the requirements is to set up your items pipeline according to whether it's files or images appropriately.

Still that discrepancy that I point it out of the fact that does stack-trace still says that it's downloading I find questionable but please review the official docs and/ or update your question to include everything. Though I can see how you might think that those two configuration settings you provided would seem like the appropriate lines to provide, given the fact that air log says that the file exceeded the max limit. I'm willing to bet that you have not configured this project properly.

https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/media-pipeline.html

### Update

I'm just now taking note that:

1) You set the DL max to unlimited ("0")

```
'DOWNLOAD_MAXSIZE' : 0,
'DOWNLOAD_TIMEOUT': 600
```

2) The error log shows that it stops the crawl/download because it's larger then the expected "response"; that's to say the size set to MAX which is again the default.

So, why is the setting which you clearly set to unlimited being ignored?

The answer is: correct syntax, wrong casing, according to the official docs: it should be all in lower case.

[image: https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html]

Comment: Thanks for coming back to me on this so quickly @scriptso, I have updated the question to include the extra information.  From the scrapy docs, it talks about what happens if a file can't be downloaded (the 'files' discrepancy you mention, I think):  _If some file failed downloading, an error will be logged and the file won’t be present in the files field._

Comment: I have now added information to items.py and edited the main code, having followed: http://yupengyan.com/how-to-download-a-file-with-scrapy.html.  - I am still getting the same error as above.

Comment: @RedBeard ! Updated my answer with what I seem to think is a oversight that is a logical.. also! again, Ive always declared in items file BUT how you had it in the beging...  the crawl all the way up to the dowload to dowloading up untill the "MAX SIZE" issue

Comment: @RedBeard  !  The discrpency I spoke of is that in the spider... You declared but you "file_urls" but not "files" ... in this case, as in the majority in this situation... are bothe the same response path

Comment: Thanks for coming back to me - I've updated for settings.py (not much in there) - lowercase actually comes back worse (the crawl stops immediately after it recognises that the size is >1024mb, I think capitalised is still correct.  Changing the order of the 3 custom settings seems to try but I get the connection lost error (see updated post) - thanks again!

Comment: @RedBeard Oh!!  Im taking this hands own... give me 15 minutes, Ill be  recreating this prjects real fast and see whats what!

Comment: @RedBeard As im going over you updated answer as Im recreating this scenario... I read ... that you have configed the pipe line... thats 1 i 3 required changed to get this all working my friend!!  as I give it a go please (if you havent already..) check out this project ( https://github.com/eloyz/reddit )... clone and run it ... there was something wonky About this project... like the need to comments out some config to get the second spider to work but yeah...  You have to understand there are few but absolute requirements to get scrapy workn! [CONTINUING NEXT COMMENT BOX]

Comment: (Hopeully by next reponse here I can start a chat room... youll se what I mean)... The requirements is to set up your pipelines, the enable it in your settings file (more often the not also enabling custom piplines in settings), enabling other middlewares LIKE THE DOWN MIDDLEWARE! YOU HAVE NOT ENABLED IT!! ... And the fact that your items MUST include the required keys.... basically it! THOUGH I KNOW how dawnting it may seem at first because not having scrapies logic down to a science but I promis after you get the first one wrking its pretty straight forward...

Comment: @RedBeard also!

 `yield {
            'file_urls': [download_url]
        }`
you still havent declared 'files' in your spider or you forgot to update that on  the question??

Comment: @RedBeard SO!  Since I was hopping to kick start the "Start chat room" feature by commenting a few times ... no luck... so will be deleting comments and help continue buildng my own.... word of advise would be to really read the docs step by step... using that redit projects i link to you as a refrence...your missing some substantial configuring!

Answer (score 0):

The errors you've been encountered might be occurred by **Memory Error**.
Can you type the command below in your console to check whether you are running 32-bit or 64-bit Python.

```
python -c 'import sys;print("64bit" if sys.maxsize > 2**32 else "32bit")'
```

If you use 32bit version, conversion into Python 64bit might solve your problem.